# Cannot create latex / pdf file : org-publish-project and org-latex-export-to-pdf

Tags: org-export

I have a simple org file, **koe.org** :

```
#+title:  Testing
#+author: Kari Marttila
#+date:   2022-06-10

#+OPTIONS: toc:2

#+PROPERTY: EXPORT_FILE_NAME koe.pdf

Testing
```

and a simple file, which comprises my latex/pdf conversion configuration, **run-koe.el** :

```
(require 'org)
(require 'ox-latex)
(require 'ox-publish)

(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(
        ("org-koe"
         :base-directory "."
         :base-extension "org"
         :publishing-directory "."
         :recursive nil
         :publishing-function org-latex-export-to-pdf
         :headline-levels 4
         :auto-preamble t
         )
         ("org" :components ("org-koe"))
      ))
```

When I apply inside the org document in the Emacs editor, the command `org-latex-export-to-pdf` , both the `tex` file and the `pdf` file gets created correctly.

But if I run this setup in command line like this:

```
emacs -u "$(id -un)" --batch -l run-koe.el --eval '(org-publish-project "org" t)'
```

I get this output:

```
λ> emacs -u "$(id -un)" --batch -l run-koe.el --eval '(org-publish-project "org" t)'
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/00debian.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...
Loading /home/kari/.emacs.d/customizations/shell-integration.el (source)...
Loading /home/kari/.emacs.d/customizations/navigation.el (source)...
Loading /home/kari/.emacs.d/.recentf...
Cleaning up the recentf list...
Cleaning up the recentf list...done (0 removed)
Loading /home/kari/.emacs.d/customizations/ui.el (source)...
Loading /home/kari/.emacs.d/customizations/editing.el (source)...
Loading /home/kari/.emacs.d/customizations/misc.el (source)...
Loading /home/kari/.emacs.d/customizations/elisp-editing.el (source)...
Loading /home/kari/.emacs.d/customizations/setup-clojure.el (source)...
Loading /home/kari/.emacs.d/customizations/setup-js.el (source)...
Loading /home/kari/.org-timestamps/org-koe.cache...
Publishing file /a/tmp/koe.org using ‘org-latex-export-to-pdf’
Output file: koe.pdf
Initializing asynchronous export process
```

There are two issues:

1. I cannot figure out how to provide the pdf file name so that it is not asked interactively.
2. No `tex` or `pdf` file gets generated.

I am using:

```
Ubuntu 20.04
GNU Emacs 26.3
Org 9.4.6
```

Comment: I experimented a little with org latex/pdf conversion. I just realized that maybe one way is to add all configuration inside the actual org document, and then just somehow in the command line run the latex/pdf conversion for the document.

Comment: I experimented a bit with this and I now realize that it is better to have the configuration (toc, footnotes...) in the document itself.

Comment: The only error is that you tried to use the export function rather than the publish function in your `org-publish-project-alist` for its publishing function. Otherwise, it works fine: see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `org-latex-export-to-pdf` as a publishing function: it does not have the right signature. Most (all?) exporters define a function for publishing, e.g. the manual uses `org-html-publish-to-html` in its example. You should try `org-latex-publish-to-pdf` instead of `org-latex-export-to-pdf`:

```el
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(
        ("org-koe"
         :base-directory "."
         :base-extension "org"
         :publishing-directory "."
         :recursive nil
         :publishing-function org-latex-publish-to-pdf
         :headline-levels 4
         :auto-preamble t
         )
         ("org" :components ("org-koe"))
      ))
```

Comment: Just curious: did you try this and did it work?